# Offset grouped animations

Tags: phaser-framework, pixi.js

I have a group of sprites that are all the same in a loop. What would be the best way to offset each animation frame, so they all don't animate at the same frame.

Answer (score 3):

I set an index on the sprites, then used modulus to target every second sprite, and then used:

```
sprite.animations.next(frameNumber);
```

to offset the frame